# I have 2 pandas dataframes and want to pull values from one dataframe to fill in columns of the other?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My data is relating to NBA match results, my first data frame is:

```
INDEX TEAM  OFFRTG  DEFRTG  NETRTG  AST%    AST/TO  ASTRATIO    OREB%   DREB%   REB%    TOV%    EFG%    TS% PACE    PIE
0   Atlanta Hawks   108.8   93.4    15.4    44.7    1.13    13.0    44.4    61.7    53.5    16.5    47.1    49.7    91.00   66.2
1   Boston Celtics  95.4    84.2    11.2    47.7    0.84    12.6    24.7    69.6    48.2    19.0    45.9    51.9    97.75   60.1
2   Charlotte Bobcats   90.8    111.6   -20.8   64.0    1.23    13.6    32.1    64.1    45.7    14.9    35.8    45.1    86.50   31.2
3   Chicago Bulls   96.9    100.0   -3.1    63.3    0.95    14.3    38.1    69.3    53.0    20.6    41.5    50.7    96.25   50.5
4   Cleveland Cavaliers 100.6   92.9    7.7 60.9    1.05    16.0    32.1    71.6    54.1    20.6    49.3    54.1    90.50   61.2
```

Sorry if the above is messy but basically its the monthly stats of all the teams.

My second data frame contains match results for a given month as follows:

```
INDEX   Team1   Team1Score  Team2   Team2Score  Team1Win    Team1Home
0   Cleveland Cavaliers 85  Boston Celtics  90  0   0
1   Milwaukee Bucks 95  Chicago Bulls   108 0   0
2   Portland Trail Blazers  76  Los Angeles Lakers  96  0   0
3   Toronto Raptors 95  Philadelphia 76ers  84  1   0
4   New Jersey Nets 95  Washington Wizards  85  1   0
```

Basically, I want to add the columns Team1OFFRTG and all the other stats for each team to compare one team's stats to the others in order to 'predict' the Team1Win variable.

How can I combine the tables to create the final data frame necessary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)

```
teams = pd.DataFrame({"team": ["T0", "T1", "T2", "T3", "T4", "T5"],
                     "A": ["A0", "A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5"]})

t1_stats = teams.add_prefix("T1_")
t2_stats = teams.add_prefix("T2_")

games = pd.DataFrame({"gameID": ["G0", "G1", "G2"],
                      "T1": [ "T0", "T2", "T4"],
                      "T2": [ "T1", "T5", "T3"],
                      "X": ["X0", "X1", "X2"]})

games_with_team_stats = games.merge(t1_stats, "left", left_on="T1", right_on="T1_team").merge(t2_stats, left_on="T2", right_on="T2_team")
```

Merge works [like a SQL join](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/comparison/comparison_with_sql.html#join) but has one major drawback - you can't rename the keys of the merged Dataframe during the merge process. It seems the simplest option for you is to create 2 temporary Dataframes which have the appropriate column names for your merge.

Answer (score 0):

The solution provided is correct, so accept that solution, but you could also add the prefix in the line that you do the merge as well:

```
import pandas as pd

stats = pd.DataFrame([
   ['Atlanta Hawks',   108.8 ,  93.4  ,  15.4 ,   44.7  ,  1.13  ,  13.0  ,  44.4  ,  61.7  ,  53.5 ,   16.5  ,  47.1 ,   49.7  ,  91.00 ,  66.2],
   ['Boston Celtics',  95.4  ,  84.2  ,  11.2  ,  47.7 ,   0.84  ,  12.6  ,  24.7  ,  69.6 ,   48.2,    19.0 ,   45.9  ,  51.9  ,  97.75  , 60.1],
   ['Charlotte Bobcats',   90.8 ,   111.6 ,  -20.8  , 64.0  ,  1.23  ,  13.6  ,  32.1  ,  64.1  ,  45.7  ,  14.9  ,  35.8 ,   45.1  ,  86.50 ,  31.2],
   ['Chicago Bulls',   96.9,    100.0 ,  -3.1  ,  63.3 ,   0.95  ,  14.3  ,  38.1  ,  69.3  ,  53.0  ,  20.6  ,  41.5 ,   50.7 ,   96.25 ,  50.5],
   ['Cleveland Cavaliers', 100.6 ,  92.9 ,   7.7, 60.9   , 1.05 ,   16.0    ,32.1 ,   71.6,    54.1,    20.6  ,  49.3 ,   54.1 ,   90.50  , 61.2]],
   columns=['TEAM','OFFRTG','DEFRTG','NETRTG','AST%','AST/TO','ASTRATIO','OREB%','DREB%','REB%','TOV%','EFG%',
         'TS%','PACE','PIE'])

matchups = pd.DataFrame([
   ['Cleveland Cavaliers', 85 , 'Boston Celtics' , 90,  0 ,  0],
   ['Milwaukee Bucks', 95 , 'Chicago Bulls' ,  108, 0 ,  0],
   ['Portland Trail Blazers',  76 , 'Los Angeles Lakers' , 96 , 0  , 0],
   ['Toronto Raptors', 95 , 'Philadelphia 76ers',  84 , 1 ,  0],
   ['New Jersey Nets', 95 , 'Washington Wizards' , 85 , 1 ,  0 ]],
   columns = ['Team1','Team1Score','Team2','Team2Score','Team1Win','Team1Home'])


df = matchups.merge(stats.add_prefix('Team1'), how='left', left_on=['Team1'], right_on=['Team1TEAM']).drop(['Team1TEAM'],axis=1).merge(stats.add_prefix('Team2'), how='left', left_on=['Team2'], right_on=['Team2TEAM']).drop(['Team2TEAM'],axis=1)
```

**Output:**

```
print(df.to_string())
                    Team1  Team1Score               Team2  Team2Score  Team1Win  Team1Home  Team1OFFRTG  Team1DEFRTG  Team1NETRTG  Team1AST%  Team1AST/TO  Team1ASTRATIO  Team1OREB%  Team1DREB%  Team1REB%  Team1TOV%  Team1EFG%  Team1TS%  Team1PACE  Team1PIE  Team2OFFRTG  Team2DEFRTG  Team2NETRTG  Team2AST%  Team2AST/TO  Team2ASTRATIO  Team2OREB%  Team2DREB%  Team2REB%  Team2TOV%  Team2EFG%  Team2TS%  Team2PACE  Team2PIE
0     Cleveland Cavaliers          85      Boston Celtics          90         0          0        100.6         92.9          7.7       60.9         1.05           16.0        32.1        71.6       54.1       20.6       49.3      54.1       90.5      61.2         95.4         84.2         11.2       47.7         0.84           12.6        24.7        69.6       48.2       19.0       45.9      51.9      97.75      60.1
1         Milwaukee Bucks          95       Chicago Bulls         108         0          0          NaN          NaN          NaN        NaN          NaN            NaN         NaN         NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN       NaN        NaN       NaN         96.9        100.0         -3.1       63.3         0.95           14.3        38.1        69.3       53.0       20.6       41.5      50.7      96.25      50.5
2  Portland Trail Blazers          76  Los Angeles Lakers          96         0          0          NaN          NaN          NaN        NaN          NaN            NaN         NaN         NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN       NaN        NaN       NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN        NaN          NaN            NaN         NaN         NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN       NaN        NaN       NaN
3         Toronto Raptors          95  Philadelphia 76ers          84         1          0          NaN          NaN          NaN        NaN          NaN            NaN         NaN         NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN       NaN        NaN       NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN        NaN          NaN            NaN         NaN         NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN       NaN        NaN       NaN
4         New Jersey Nets          95  Washington Wizards          85         1          0          NaN          NaN          NaN        NaN          NaN            NaN         NaN         NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN       NaN        NaN       NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN        NaN          NaN            NaN         NaN         NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN       NaN        NaN       NaN
```